# Find the length of the longest substring with all different characters in O(n) time

Tags: code-golf, string, restricted-complexity

Let's solve the [same task as in this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/204426/25315) but faster!

**Input**: a non-empty string containing letters a-z

**Output**: the length of a longest (contiguous) substring in which all letters are different

**Time and space complexity**: O(n).

The number of letters in the alphabet is 26, or O(1). Make sure you understand how your language works - e.g. if it can't "extract a substring" in O(1) time, you probably can't use substrings in your implementation - use indices instead.

The solution doesn't need to say at which position it found the longest substring, and whether there is more than one. So, for example, if it found a substring of length 26, it can stop searching (this observation will not help you write your implementation).

#### Test Cases

```
abcdefgabc -> 7
aaaaaa -> 1
abecdeababcabaa -> 5
abadac -> 3
abababab -> 2
helloworld -> 5
longest -> 7
nonrepeating -> 7
substring -> 8
herring -> 4
abracadabra -> 4
codegolf -> 6
abczyoxpicdabcde -> 10
```

(I took these directly from the other challenge)

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6), 62 bytes

Expects an array of characters.

```javascript
a=>a.map((c,i)=>a[m=(d=i-a[c],d<++j?j=d:j)<m?m:j,c]=i,j=m=0)|m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZLZbsMgEEXf@xVRnozikHSPotB8iOWH8YApiMXCTjf1313qRG2c4EFihHTu1XBBwxu0GFTTLZ3noq9ZD@wFqIUmyzBXJB4KyzLO1BIKLHO@Wyz0XjO@1WRn93arcyyZyjWzbE2@bY/etd4IarzM6qyglM6hQi5qGdu8JGR2rNVq9nyTgoc6A0/wbRKuRLSGKlrH7aSK8GMaBg547Xw/AQ9rhEf4LgW/CmP8uw@Gjy@YHMN4J0XbjeeYSsN5F0QjoFNO/imm4PZQtV04J4/wJj1zuEQH@CGdRgCM6cX2L5iCMX4k6U19Gd1T2hm/Pv1Ho5AP32QQ/T73uv8B)

#### Commented

```javascript
a =>                // a[] = input array, reused as an object to keep
                    // track of the last position of each character
a.map((c, i) =>     // for each character c at position i in a[]:
  a[                // 
    m = (           //   m is the maximum length of a valid substring
      d = i - a[c], //   let d be the difference between the current
                    //   position and the last position of c (NaN if
                    //   c has not been seen so far)
      d < ++j ?     //   increment j; if d is less than j:
        j = d       //     we have to force j to d
      :             //   else:
        j           //     keep the incremented value of j
    ) < m ?         //   if j is less than m:
      m             //     leave m unchanged
    :               //   else:
      j,            //     update m to j
    c               //   update a[c] ...
  ] = i,            //   ... to i
  j = m = 0         //   start with j = m = 0
) | m               // end of map(); return m
```

Comment: Wow, this must be the most obscure code I have seen in quite some time!

Comment: `d = i - a[c]` -- Maybe I misunderstand your explanation, but `c` is one of the characters of the array, so how are we indexing into the array with `c`?

Comment: @Jonah Any array is also an object in JS. So `a['foo']` is referencing the `foo` property of the underlying object of the array `a`.

Comment: Oh I get it, it is undefined at first and then you are adding that as a property.... Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>10</s> 6 bytes

```
UÞx↔tL
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBVCIsIiIsIlXDnnjihpR0TCIsIiIsImFiY2RlZmdhYmNcbmFhYWFhYVxuYWJlY2RlYWJhYmNhYmFhXG5hYmFkYWNcbmFiYWJhYmFiXG5oZWxsb3dvcmxkXG5sb25nZXN0XG5ub25yZXBlYXRpbmdcbnN1YnN0cmluZ1xuaGVycmluZ1xuYWJyYWNhZGFicmFcbmNvZGVnb2xmIl0=)

Shorter than the Vyxal answer in the original challenge. \$O(nk!)\$ where \$n\$ is the length of the string and \$k\$ is the number of unique characters so it times out when \$k\geq 10\$.

```
U      # uniquify
 Þx    # combinations without replacement
   ↔   # keep only those that are in input
    t  # tail
     L # length
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org), <del>129</del> 127 bytes

```rust
|s:&[u8]|{let(mut a,mut d,mut e)=(-1,[-1;128],0);for(i,j)in(0..).zip(s){let f=*j as usize;a=a.max(d[f]);d[f]=i;e=e.max(i-a)}e};
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ddJLboMwEABQqcucwmVR2RVQyBfFoj1IlIUBmzoiBtlGTUNQD9JNFu0Fepv2NHVggZESkGYk63k8sufzS9ZKn3-YAHvCBUSgmRRUAxZ_15p50e_HSa0fNnW0PTVmHe5rDYh7iVkXKYqhF7obL8ThNNq6AcKslJC7O2SqBb6P_COvoEJNX_VxB4gCteJHiklM_D05wGzDtghfYswxjWm3yD2CWtrivo2_O1xJLnQh7qGzAs36pXVcBhOHJGlGWW6SgxAGT0_AewaryYBDG3ffBfYutNxiVJSaqiQxVU2wNiysDbPRBpKRdHAzy03HrvsHOb3RwistivKtlEV2_XT7DopS5FTpAa5uQFEKSStKNBf5dR1ZWtWJ0nJEI4vOR93KMZzfgCSRJDV3ZdJ1vLRwWmY0Lws2yKX9sMF4DI7v5aHiadZNhPXGwaTtZ-h87vM_)

Comment: -6 bytes by changing parameter to `&[usize]` and getting rid of the cast. [ATO](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hZJLboMwEIalLnMKyiKyK0AhfSEI6S26iaLIwDh1ZDAyRk1COEk3WbQn6Gna09Qxm0DV1JZmLM_nf2Y0fnuXdaWOn7SwcsIKhK1mxEFZdBV_1Iq6wdfuUIXjRV2xPSwPjY6hvFYWcU42MxZwjFzfWbh-5E-DpTPBERUSMWeDteLE87C3ZyWqcGOU45tNRGLi5WSLsgVd4uhkYxZBDOaSuQS30EZdAd9XXvesqyNYHugKjSuPKZAIe6koGWT6kJMSmSrDkEqRnyKcQ6rCcPYM6cyE5nOEcTQqJSsUL66R_Wg14VNrOxQlNknSDOhaO7sP-eeQWQPgvqcCWoYkWkabIXnbI0lGhrmmfcDsC9legHPxKiTP7L8b46JYQ6UuEIUoJJRAFCvWAyw4w6o6qZT8zdz1KpL_ECSRJNWtazegHs6oVGSwFpwOZzHpT2y_E9uSpZkZnmHb7tscj53_AQ)

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 43 bytes

```
≔⦃⦄θ≔⁰η≔⁰ζＦＳ«→≔⌊⟦⊕ζ⁻ⅈ∨§θι⁰⟧ζ§≔θιⅈ¿›ζη≔ζη»Ｉη
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VU-xasNADJ3jrxCZdHCBjKWZQofiITS0SyFkOJ9l-yA-J3dyKA75ki4ZWtqt39Mv6G9UwTe0i9DTe9J7ev20jQm2M7vL5b3nanbz_bOM0dUeT2cNB7XIEpxraP6hQVDVBcDc73t-4uB8jUrBKZusuiPh7aOrGxbRJO2snHdt3-Im9zZQS56pxEFpEKKP-IzSPgRccu5LesGDBieTuVJbNbqlQ38FGmTtSrkK8D6QYQo4XKMqSLbDGPycrSUh452JjEIv3mJhY3r6YzOdHXfT7ZcpyJZkClNYKWZkfwE) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔⦃⦄θ≔⁰η≔⁰ζ
```

Start with an empty dictionary of previous indices, and zero best and current run length.

```
ＦＳ«
```

Loop over the input string.

```
→
```

Increment the canvas X coordinate. This keeps track of the current index without using another variable.

```
≔⌊⟦⊕ζ⁻ⅈ∨§θι⁰⟧ζ
```

Try to increment the current run length, but reduce it to the difference of the current index with the previous index of the current character (or 0 if the character has not been seen previously).

```
§≔θιⅈ
```

Update the last seen index of the current character.

```
¿›ζη≔ζη
```

Update the best run length. (`≔⌈⟦ηζ⟧η` also works for the same byte count.)

```
»Ｉη
```

Output the final best run length.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 52 bytes

```python
lambda A,b="":max(len(b:=a+b.split(a)[0])for a in A)
```

Storing b back-to-front saves a byte.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NU9BTsMwELznFVZOsUhRgAJVpCBVvfYHwGEd26kl12s5rtryFS6VEHyGF_Q3rJ3glbwzszvr9eePP8cdusuX7t6-D1EvVtelhb2QwNa16Mqy3cOpsspVou3gRtyO3ppYAX9t3rnGwIAZx9Z89m6StE0SevI0vC2YqZF1bDs7S7Z4YSUvWBKNixUS9iEhXRle4zzqcv0F0UulB0rJ81xAPgnfFSAUFUFQka4sPpIIEnLzQ8I5ErsvdspaPGKwcuq06AY1xmmuQxeUVxCNGyZlPIgxhpmuyB3-yZIGB-jpHUqT0KNUA1qd2BOV-48znrzpZd4_r9tMf_oD)

#### Original [Python](https://www.python.org), 53 bytes

```python
lambda A,b="":max(len(b:=b.split(a)[-1]+a)for a in A)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NU9BTsMwELznFVZOsUhQC7RUkYJUce0PgMM6tlNLrtdyXNHyFS6VEHyGF_Q3rJ3glbwzszvr9eePP8c9usuX7l6_j1E3m-vKwkFIYNtadGXZHuBUWeUq0XbidvTWxAr4S7N8uwGuMTBgxrEtn83PSdolCT2ZFrwtmKmRdWw3m0vWPLGSFyyJxsUKCfuQkK4Mr3Eedbn-guil0gOl5HksIJ-ElwUIRUUQVKQriysSQUJuvk84R2J3xV5Zi-8YrJw6LbpBjXGa69AF5RVE44ZJGY9ijGGmG3KHf_JAgwP09A6lSehRqgGtTmxN5f7jjCdvepn3z-supj_9AQ)

I'm not sure there are many methods that are not O(n). This one is

#### O(n) because

Main loop is over the input string (~> n iterations). Body takes linear time in the length of b which never exceeds the (fixed) size of the alphabet (~> O(1)).

Taken together that gives linear time (in n); taking the max does not change this.

Answer (score 3):

## Excel (ms365), 149 bytes

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=LET(x,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),MAX(MAP(REDUCE(0,x,LAMBDA(y,z,VSTACK(y,MID(A1,z,x)))),LAMBDA(q,(LEN(q)=COUNTA(UNIQUE(MID(q,SEQUENCE(LEN(q)),1))))*LEN(q)))))
```

---

Thought I'd also chuck in a Python solution though I'm sure someone more proficient with Python will post something much smoother:

```
from itertools import combinations
s = 'abcdefgabc'
print(max([(len(set(z))==len(z))*len(z)for z in[s[x:y]for x,y in combinations(range(len(s)+1),r=2)]]))
```

Or, with regular expressions:

```
import regex as r
s = 'abczyoxpicdabcde'
print(max([len(i[0])for i in r.findall(r'((.)((?!\2)(.)(?<!\2.*\4.*\4))*)',s,overlapped=1)]))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 10 bytes

```
/@~0""]@,;:$/`%_$$
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY4xDsIwDEV3H6MqG6iMCJZeBIGduGmlKKmSVAUGds7A0gWxcxtug5tiS372_5L1n2_XEVmO0_QaUrPZfar6vi2KY70-7MvqvDqV5WL8_en7QFKaGyMAzAVILBKSSDLmGzWqGbmhZWv96IPVYL0zHBM47wL3jKlzBuJAMYV5azlkIgVU8kQAyms23jYiqtvVX_pO6ZxhSfQD)

Time complexity: \$\mathcal O(nr)\$, where \$r\$ is the result.

```
/      Right fold
@       each line of input
~ 0 ""  with a starting value of (0, "")
        (ch, accumulator) => (
]        max
@         accumulator.first
,         length of
;          s :=
:           join
$            ch
/            fold
`%            split
_              accumulator.second
$              by ch
$             first
         , s)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 12 bytes

```
e.MZml=+eckd
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P1XPNyo3x1Y7NTk75f9/pcSk5JTUtHQgpQQA)

Port of [@loopy walt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/257026/73054)'s answer. Could replace `.MZ` with `S` but that would *technically* make it \$O(n\log(n))\$.

#### Explanation

```
e.MZml=+eckddQ    # implicitly add dQ to the end of the program
                  # implicitly assign Q = eval(input())
    m        Q    # map the letters of Q to lambda d
      =+eckdd     #   k = k.split(d)[-1] + d
     l            #   length(k)
e.MZ              # get the maximum
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 146 bytes

```hs
import Data.Array
f=snd.foldl(\(l,m)(i,c)->
 (l//[(b,max(l!b)(l!c))|b<-['a'..'z']]//[(c,i)],
 max m(i-l!c)))(accumArray(+)0('a','z')[],0).zip[1..]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hc3RDoIgGIbhc6@CXBv/vxDtPNvaugviAFGKBeLQtnLdO5En39Hz7nuo@Tk4l5L1U4gLuapF8UuM6lOYdh57boLrHdzAMY9gmcbqXBBwdS2gY169we06zKMRv92pElRRzulKpfwTzSxKVpAMiQdbbQ5Baf3y2wscsIHcsJygkKxBvtpJHDmXySs7tlO047I3pQ79cA/OlOkH)